# Cannot install drivers from ubuntu 16.04 media

Tags: drivers, wireless, software-installation, dvd

I have a PC with a usb wireless network card which isn't identified by ubuntu. I'm trying to install some software from the install CD, however when I open "Software & Updates" the "Installable from CD-ROM/DVD" field doesn't list the install CD with a checkbox next to it but says "To install from a CD-ROM or DVD, insert the medium into the drive".

**How can I get Ubuntu to recognize that the CD is indeed in the drive?**

Note, I know *how* to install from the CD-ROM, however, I'm having problems doing so, namely on the "Software & Updates" window, "Ubuntu Software" tab of the "Installable from CD-ROM/DVD" field is blank. It should list the install CD and I should be able to select it as an installation source.

**SOLVED**

I manually mounted the cdrom to /media/cdrom

**Wireless issues remain:**

I've installed the broadcom STA drivers from the install media but the wireless card I have (BCM42321) seems to be not supported. The ndiswrapper doesn't seem to be in the install DVD. It's going to be a pain to download and copy the ndiswrapper package onto this computer. Is there anything else I can try before doing that?

Comment: Comment deleted. However, have you updated the software repositories? `sudo apt-get update` etc? Have you a volume management package installed like `gvfs`?

Comment: @GTRONICK Yes. But before I did that I edited the /etc/apt/sources.list file and commented out all of the internet sources (I'm not connected to the internet) and uncommented the top cdrom source. The `sudo apt-get update` succeeds. I next type `sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter` but this says "Media change: please insert the disc labeled Ubuntu 16.04.1 ... " in the drive /media/cdrom. That is inserted but mounted on a different location.

Comment: Are you talking about the Ubuntu install DVD or the USB wireless driver CD? Unless the driver file is a .deb file (doubtful), I don't think that Software and Updates will recognize it as installable. Moreover, it is quite doubtful that the driver that came on a CD with your USB wireless is new enough to compile on 16.04. Please tell us about the device from the terminal: `lsusb` and we'll help.

Comment: @MustafaOzturk You could try to mount the disk manually in the required location, remember to umount it first  from the current mount point. You could require root access to do so.

Comment: @chili555 the I'm trying to install drivers for broadcom BCM43231. I installed the broadcom STA drivers from the install CD but that didn't help.

Comment: @GTRONICK that worked actually and I was able to install b43-fwcutter. But it didn't fix my wireless card unfortunately.

Comment: The Ubuntu install DVD or the driver CD that came with your USB??? Are you trying to install drivers for the internal Broadcom or the USB or switching back and forth to confuse poor old Chili?

Comment: What is the terminal response when you do: `sudo modprobe wl`? I suspect Secure Boot! If it is a Secure Boot issue, neither STA nor ndiswrapper nor the USB drivers will work.

Comment: @chili555 sorry. I'll take a step back: I'm trying to install ubuntu on a 3 year old desktop PC that has a internal CD-ROM that works fine. It also has an internal gigabit ethernet card, but because of reasons I do not want to get into, I cannot use wired internet. So I purchased a wireless card and I'm trying to connect using it, however ubuntu doesn't recognize the card with whatever drivers are installed by default,

Comment: @chili555 `sudo modprobe wl` returns nothing

Comment: How about: `iwconfig` and: `rfkill list all`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49735/discussion-between-mustafa-ozturk-and-chili555).